# Laravel Excel export row number starts from total row count instead of 1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I know there is a very simple solution requiring minor adjustment to my code but I'm stuck and I have wasted a lot of time trying to find the solution.

Using Laravel Excel I am able to export successfully except that the row numbers are off.

I was able to deduce that the numbering begins with the total number rows within the collection, but they are supposed to begin at 1.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
protected $table_data;
private $row = 0;

public function __construct(array $table_data)
{
    $this->table_data = $table_data;

}

public function model(array $row)
{

    ++$this->row;

}

public function columnFormats(): array
  {
      return [
          'E' => '0',
      ];
  }

public function map($table_data): array
{

  $department = (empty($table_data['department'])) ? 'Cast' : $table_data['department']['name'];

    return [
        ++$this->row,
        $department,
        $table_data['name'],
        $table_data['name_eng'],
        $table_data['phone_number'],
        $table_data['email'],
    ];
}

public function startCell(): string
{
   return 'A6';
}


public function drawings()
{
    $drawing = new Drawing();
    $drawing->setName('Logo');
    $drawing->setPath(public_path('/images/form_logo.png'));
    $drawing->setHeight(90);
    $drawing->setCoordinates('A1');

    return $drawing;
}

public function headings(): array
{
    return [
      [
        '#',
        'Department',
        'Position/Role',
        'Name',
        'Phone',
        'Email',
      ]
    ];
}

public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
{
  $sheet->getStyle('A6:F6')->getFill()->applyFromArray(['fillType' => 'solid','rotation' => 0, 'color' => ['rgb' => '7BC1FA'],]);
  $styleArray = array(
    'font'  => array(
        'bold'  => true,
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FFFFFF'),
        'size'  => 12,
        'name'  => 'Arial'
    ));
  $sheet->getStyle('A6:F6')->applyFromArray($styleArray)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true)->setHorizontal('left');
}

public function array(): array
{
    return $this->table_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably `++$this->row` being executed at least twice as often as you expect. I'm not sure if that's because you have it both in `model` and `map` method but it might as well go wrong if it's only in `map` or you are not using import features and it's in `model`.

So I'd suggest a different solution:
If you are only exporting Data and specifically using the [array](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html#using-arrays) approach for your data you could add the row index on the data set and use it in `map` and so on:

```php
public function __construct(array $table_data)
{
    $newTableData = [];
    foreach($table_data as $index => $data) {
       // add row index
       $newTableData[] = array_merge(['row' => $index], $data);
    }
    $this->table_data = $newTableData;
}

//...

public function map($table_data): array
{
    $department = (empty($table_data['department'])) ? 'Cast' : $table_data['department']['name'];

    return [
        // use row index
        $table_data['row'],
        $department,
        $table_data['name'],
        $table_data['name_eng'],
        $table_data['phone_number'],
        $table_data['email'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks so much @makadev. Your solution worked and was very clean!